# database tables lost after re-install wampserver

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I've read some questions before this and no answer exactly what this happenned.
I'm using wampserver 2.5 x64. I have many databases in localhost. After reinstalled wampserver (exactly the same install file of wampserver), some databases are OK but someones are no table inside. 
Ex: I got DB A, B, C, D. I uninstalled and reinstalled wampserver. DB A is OK, B or C no table, D is OK.
I think you guys got the same problems to me but I found no answer. 
Is there anybody get this problem and solution to solve?

Edited:
The *.ibd, *.frm are still in the data folder. But when I executed the select statement, I got this Error Code: 1146. Table  doesn't exist.

Comment: better to take backup and than doing re-installation or repairs

Comment: That gets a lot of time because I got more than 40 databaes T.T

Comment: this many help http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/07/19/12-steps-to-rebuild-your-wamp-server-without-losing-your-data/

Comment: Thanks Syed. The problem is that I didn't backup. Now the tables are lost.

Comment: RE: _That gets a lot of time because I got more than 40 databaes_ How long will it take to recreate the lost databases? Longer I would say than taking a backup.

Comment: You're right, Riggs! But now what is the solution to restore or how to fix that for wampserver. I've never get this with any versions of wampserver before. I posted the problem in WampServer Forums. Hope they will find out to fix. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I already looked at it on WampServer forum. I think you need a real MySQL expert for this. You could try adding some more info about what type of databases they are and i.e. MYISAM/INNODB I assume Innodb

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem by myself was that all lost tables were InnoDB Engine. Next time, I just create tables using MyISAM Engine. You can uninstall and reinstall wampserver as many time as you wish. It's easy for localhost but not to find a hosting service with MyISAM database as I know.

I just leave the answer to warning some guys don't know about this. I'm sorry if my question bothered you.

Comment: Next time you consider reinstalling or upgrading WAMPServer take a look at this post on the WAMPServer forum [Installing a new release of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) And of course BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP

Comment: Thanks Riggs! I did read and followed to reinstall wampserver before I posted my answer. The InnoDB tables still lost. After I converted all InnoDB into MyISAM tables, I just uninstall wamp and reinstall override on the same wamp folder. My 43 databases are working well now and the new one is coming in MyISAM database.

Comment: Did you re-install the same version of WAMPServer or a newer versions?

Comment: I did installation with the same installer. I downloaded wamserver 2.5 x64 a month ago and saved the install file in my computer. I uninstalled wampserver and re-install with the install file I saved and got the problem as I said. But now is fine. I just converted all InnoDB into MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

## working solution

If you have made the copy of bin/data folder and not able to recover, then do the following steps :

```
1. Install Old wamp
2. Restore them in the old wamp
3. Export using phpmyadmin
4. Import in the new wamp
```

hope it helps.